# F# : I need to format my output to only contain comma-separated integers, rather than the list format in F#

Tags: list, functional-programming, f#, formatting

I have a function that takes a list of Integer values and returns the same. In the body of the function I
need it to print out the output list before returning it. Currently it prints out the output below. I would like to print the items in the list out separated by commas *without* using any type of loop.

My **output** currently looks like:
`Even numbers : [8; 10; 12; 14]`

My **desired output formatting** looks like:
`Even numbers : 8 10 12 14`

```
let evens_only (x : List<Int32>) : List<Int32> =
    let output_list = x |> List.filter(fun y -> (y % 2) = 0)
    printfn "Even numbers : %A" output_list
    output_list
```

Comment: Actually, the simplest soltution here is to just do a string replace.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding. I tried mapping the List<Int32> to a List<String> where I converted each item to a String. The output was the same but with each item surrounded by quotes like this: `Even numbers : ["8"; "10"; "12"; "14"]`

Comment: %A in sprintf prints uses default formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just map `printf` over the list (`List.iter` is similar to `List.map` in its functionality for this example).

```
let evens_only (x : List<Int32>) : List<Int32> =
    let output_list = x |> List.filter(fun y -> (y % 2) = 0)
    printf "Even numbers : "
    List.iter (fun i -> printf "%i " i) output_list
    printfn "" //extra newline
    output_list
```

Output:

```
> evens_only [8; 10; 12; 14];;
Even numbers : 8 10 12 14 
val it : List<Int32> = [8; 10; 12; 14]
```